# Javascript timepicker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to use the [Timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) with grid for time as given in the slider example:

```
$('#slider_example_1').timepicker({
hourGrid: 4,
minuteGrid: 10,
timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt'
});
```

But this is not working.

Can someone please provide working JFiddle for it. I am new to Javascript and CSS and so not able to figure out the issue.

I found this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9xc7/3/) but timepicker part is not working. However, above example from the Trent's website works.

Comment: Did you follow all the directions on https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon ?  Post the html code you have for the page you are trying it on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the jquery plugin url is no longer available. Check the working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9xc7/76/)

Following is wrong

`http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js`

Update the URL to

`http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js`